# How can I add new column with ifelse

Tags: r

I am a beginner of R studio.
Here is the data below.

| logic1 | logic2 | logic3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
| FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
| TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
| TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
| FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |
| TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
| TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
| FALSE | FALSE | TRUE |
| TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
| TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |

I'd like to add a new data column on the right. If (logic1, logic2, logic3) is (TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), add TRUE. If not, add FALSE. For this, I made code like the below.

```
x <- c(df2$logic1, df2$logic2, df2$logic33)
y<- c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
x1 <- ifelse(x %in% y, TRUE, FALSE)
df2$result <- x1
```

However, the Rstudio result shows like below.

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, result, value = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, : 
replacement has 22 rows, data has 11
```

I've tried to find various ways in Google, but I couldn't find the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do -

```
df2 <- transform(df2, result = logic1 & !logic2 & !logic3)
df2

#   logic1 logic2 logic3 result
#1    TRUE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
#2   FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
#3    TRUE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
#4    TRUE   TRUE   TRUE  FALSE
#5    TRUE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
#6   FALSE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE
#7    TRUE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
#8    TRUE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
#9   FALSE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE
#10   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
#11   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
```

If you don't want to refer columns individually (`logic1`, `logic2`, ... etc) and want to use `y` which can change or is dynamic then one way would be to use `sweep`.

```
y <- c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
df2$result <- rowSums(sweep(df2, 2, y, `==`)) == ncol(df2)
```

Comment: Thank you, Ronak. I've been looking for a way to do this for a long time, but it's finally solved. Thanks to you, I can move on to the next step.